# how can I better run my code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The exercise is as follows, given an array with multiple arrays inside, return the sum of the product subtraction with the LMC. I managed to create the code, but is passing 12000ms of response and wanted to optimize my code, I still have difficulty with it, can you help me? Follow the code below.
The expected result is 840.

```js
let pairs = [[15,18], [4,5], [12,60]];
function sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs (pairs)
{
    let product = [];
    let prodResult = 1;
    let LMC = [];
    let result = 0;
    // take a product
    for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length;i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < pairs[i].length;j++)
        {   
            prodResult *= pairs[i][j]
        }
        product.push(prodResult);
        if(prodResult != 0)
        {
            prodResult = 1
        }
    }
    // take a LMC
    for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length;i++)
    {
        let m = pairs[i][0];
        let n = pairs[i][1];
        let a = pairs[i][0];
        let b = pairs[i][1];
        let mmc = 0;
        let r = 0
        do
        {
            r = m%n;
            m=n;
            n=r;
        } while (r != 0);

        mmc = (a * b)/m
        LMC.push(mmc)
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < product.length; i++){
        result += product[i]-LMC[i]
    }
    return result
}

console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs(pairs));
```

Comment: LMC = minimum least common multiple ?

Comment: Yeah bro, in brazil is MMC

Answer (score 0):

You can do all calculation in `single loop` only which will reduce your run time complexity.

```js
let pairs = [[15,18], [4,5], [12,60]];

function sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs (pairs) {
    let result = 0;
    // take a product
    for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length;i++) {
        let prodResult = 1; 
        for(let j = 0; j < pairs[i].length;j++) {   
            prodResult *= pairs[i][j]
        }
        const lcmResult = lcm(pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);
        result += prodResult - lcmResult;
    }
    return result
}

function lcm(a, b) {
   return (a / gcd(a, b)) * b;
}

function gcd(a, b) {
  if (a === 0) {
    return b;
  }
  return gcd(b % a, a);
}

console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs(pairs));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
}
```